# Position Extraction and Tracking in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am not a good programmer, and I am new to Matlab. I have recorded video of myself juggling 3 balls of different colors (Red, White, and Yellow). I used uncompressed .avi files at 30fps, and have around 460Gb of data. My plan is to use ~1 minute of video (1800 frames) from each recording and make a 2D position (y-axis) vs. time (x-axis) graph. Each ball would be on the graph drawn in its own color. I have downloaded this script

(http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28512-simplecolordetectionbyhue--)

but I am not sure if this is a good place to start or not. Any suggestions? I can play the videos just fine using implay, but VideoReader seems to have a problem since the file is quite large.

Comment: As a new programmer, downloading a random script to perform an extremely complex task that you do not really understand is probably not going to get you very far. Consider learning the basics first, at least to the point that you have some idea of what is going on.

Comment: Hi Sean, welcome to SO.  I think it's a fine enough place to start.  Futz with it for a while, and come back to ask when you have a well defined problem you can't solve (be sure to google first!).  We'll be glad to help then!